# Connect Four WinCheck

Tags: java, swing

I'm making connect four for my high school cpt. So far I've got everything to display but the win check for it is causing problems. The spots on the game board are created by individual images of empty and filled spots on a connect four board.Immediately when run and a spot is selected, automatically yellow win when it is their turn (colors are red and yellow). Thank you for your help and if you have any further questions just ask.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import sun.audio.*;


public class ConnectFourV2p2 {

  static JFrame mainWindow;
  static JButton firstButton = new JButton("Drop");
  static JButton secondButton = new JButton("Drop");
  static JButton thirdButton = new JButton("Drop");
  static JButton fourthButton = new JButton("Drop");
  static JButton fifthButton = new JButton("Drop");
  static JButton sixthButton = new JButton("Drop");
  static JButton seventhButton = new JButton("Drop");
  static JPanel[][] gridArray = new JPanel[6][7];
  static String[][] spotOnGrid = new String[6][7];
  static JLabel emptyLabel = new JLabel();
  static JPanel emptyPanel;
  static ImageIcon emptyBox;
  static JLabel redLabel = new JLabel();
  static JPanel redPanel;
  static ImageIcon redBox;
  static JLabel yellowLabel = new JLabel();
  static JPanel yellowPanel;
  static ImageIcon yellowBox;
  static JPanel gridPanel;
  static Boolean redTurn = true;

  private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (e.getSource() == firstButton) {
        if(redTurn) {
          dropRedBox(0);
          if(winCheck("red")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
          }
        }
          else {
            dropYellowBox(0);
            winCheck("yellow");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yellow wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );}
      }

      if (e.getSource() == secondButton) {
        if(redTurn) {
          dropRedBox(1);
          if(winCheck("red")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
          }
        }
          else {
            dropYellowBox(1);
            winCheck("yellow");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yellow wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );}
        }


      if (e.getSource() == thirdButton) {
        if(redTurn) {
          dropRedBox(2);
          if(winCheck("red")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
          }
        }
          else {
            dropYellowBox(2);
            winCheck("yellow");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yellow wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );}
        }


      if (e.getSource() == fourthButton) {
        if(redTurn) {
          dropRedBox(3);
          if(winCheck("red")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
          }
        }
          else {
            dropYellowBox(3);
            winCheck("yellow");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yellow wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );}
        }


      if (e.getSource() == fifthButton) {
        if(redTurn) {
          dropRedBox(4);
          if(winCheck("red")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
          }
        }
          else {
            dropYellowBox(4);
            winCheck("yellow");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yellow wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );}
        }


      if (e.getSource() == sixthButton) {
        if(redTurn) {
          dropRedBox(5);
          if(winCheck("red")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
          }
        }
          else {
            dropYellowBox(5);
            winCheck("yellow");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yellow wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );}
        }


      if (e.getSource() == seventhButton) {
        if(redTurn) {
          dropRedBox(6);
          if(winCheck("red")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
          }
        }
          else {
            dropYellowBox(6);
            winCheck("yellow");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yellow wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );}
        }


    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    ButtonHandler listener = new ButtonHandler();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    gridPanel = new JPanel();

    mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    gridPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 7));
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 7));
    gridPanel.setBackground(new Color(255, 127, 38));



    mainPanel.add(gridPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    mainPanel.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    buttonPanel.add(firstButton);
    buttonPanel.add(secondButton);
    buttonPanel.add(thirdButton);
    buttonPanel.add(fourthButton);
    buttonPanel.add(fifthButton);
    buttonPanel.add(sixthButton);
    buttonPanel.add(seventhButton);

    firstButton.addActionListener(listener);
    secondButton.addActionListener(listener);
    thirdButton.addActionListener(listener);
    fourthButton.addActionListener(listener);
    fifthButton.addActionListener(listener);
    sixthButton.addActionListener(listener);
    seventhButton.addActionListener(listener);

    mainWindow = new JFrame("Connect Four");
    mainWindow.setContentPane(mainPanel);
    mainWindow.setSize(884, 730);
    mainWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    mainWindow.setResizable(false);

    createGrid();
    resetGrid();

  }



  public static void createGrid() {
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
        gridArray[j][k] = new JPanel();
        gridPanel.add(gridArray[j][k]);
        gridArray[j][k].setBackground(new Color(103,110,215));
      }
    }
  }

  public static void resetGrid(){
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
        gridArray[j][k].removeAll();
        gridArray[j][k].add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("emptyBox.png")));
        gridArray[j][k].revalidate();
        spotOnGrid[j][k] = "empty";
      }
    }
  }

  public static void dropRedBox(int col) {
    for(int j = 5; j >= 0; j--) {
      if(spotOnGrid[j][col].equals("empty")) {
        spotOnGrid[j][col] = "red";
        gridArray[j][col].removeAll();
        gridArray[j][col].add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("redBox.png")));
        gridArray[j][col].revalidate();
        spotOnGrid[j][col] = "red";
        redTurn = false;
        break;
      }

    }
  }

  public static void dropYellowBox(int col){
    for(int j = 5; j >=0; j--) {
      if(spotOnGrid[j][col].equals("empty")) {
        spotOnGrid[j][col] = "yellow";
        gridArray[j][col].removeAll();
        gridArray[j][col].add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("yellowBox.png")));
        gridArray[j][col].revalidate();
        spotOnGrid[j][col] = "yellow";
        redTurn = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  }


  public static boolean winCheck(String box) {
    Boolean winner = false;
    int currentRow;
    int currentCol;
    for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < 7; k++) {
        if(spotOnGrid[j][k].equals(box)) {
          currentRow = j;
          currentCol = k;

          if(((j -3) >= 0) && spotOnGrid[j -1][k].equals(box) && spotOnGrid[j -2][k].equals(box) && spotOnGrid[j -3][k].equals(box)) {         
            return true;
          }

          if(((j +3) <= 5) && spotOnGrid[j +1][k].equals(box) && spotOnGrid[j +2][k].equals(box) && spotOnGrid[j +3][k].equals(box)) {       
            return true;
          }

          if(((k -3) >= 0) && spotOnGrid[j][k -1].equals(box) && spotOnGrid[j][k -2].equals(box) && spotOnGrid[j][k -3].equals(box)) {
            return true;
          }
          if(((k +3) <= 6) && spotOnGrid[j][k +1].equals(box) && spotOnGrid[j][k +2].equals(box) && spotOnGrid[j][k +3].equals(box)) {           
            return true;
          }
          else
            return false;

        }

      }

    }
    return false;
  }

}
```

Comment: Some structural issues with your code: 1)the only thing that should be static is `main()` 2) you should separate your model (the idea of the grid) from all the GUI code 3) rework your listeners, you shouldn't be copy and pasting a bunch of code

Comment: It's not clear what exactly the question is. Can you be more specific than "is causing problems"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put `"Yellow wins"` inside an if block. That's why it always shows

Also, you look up the index of your button, so you don't have to copy and paste similar code blocks

First, declare a list

```
static List<JButton> buttonz = Arrays.asList(
    firstButton, secondButton, thirdButton, fourthButton, 
    fifthButton, sixthButton, seventhButton);
```

Then do look up inside the button handler

```
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //which button?
        int buttonIndex = buttonz.indexOf(e.getSource());

        //drop box, check win and show message 
        if (redTurn) {
            dropRedBox(buttonIndex);
            if (winCheck("red")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Red wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        } else {
            dropYellowBox(buttonIndex);
            if (winCheck("yellow"))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Yellow wins!", "Winner!", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I declare the list I get the Error: reference to List is ambiguous, both interface java.util.List in java.util and class java.awt.List in java.awt match

Comment: @user2871898 just write `import java.util.List;` this tells the compiler which `List` (`java.util.List` or `java.awt.List`) you are using

Comment: Do I still have to put it in: if (e.getSource() == firstButton){} ?

Comment: @user2871898 no... if we do that only the first button would work.

Comment: I mean do I have to put your second post inside each button separately?